# How to center align my images that are contained in a list?

Tags: html, css

I want the images in the list to be displayed in the center of the browser. Right now they are just left aligned. I tried using text align, but I'm not sure if I'm placing it in the right spot.
HTML code:

```
<article id=images>
    <h2>Images of Italy</h2>
    <ul>
    <li><img src="Images/Italy/img1.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="Images/Italy/img2.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="Images/Italy/img3.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="Images/Italy/img4.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="Images/Italy/img5.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="Images/Italy/img6.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="Images/Italy/img7.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="Images/Italy/img8.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="Images/Italy/img9.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="Images/Italy/img10.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="Images/Italy/img11.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="Images/Italy/img12.jpg"></li>     
    <li><img src="Images/Italy/img13.jpg"></li> 
    </ul>
</article>
```

CSS:

```
#images ul li
{
display: inline;
list-style: none;
}


#images img
{
text-align: center;
height: 135px;
width: 135px;
margin-left: .35rem;
margin-right: .35rem;
margin-bottom: .5rem;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to horizontally align the images, add `text-align: center;` to the `ul`